# Usage of hyphen in "bit-will"

Tags: grammaticality

This is the whole paragraph. What confuses me here that why should the author have used hyphen between bit and will here also. Is this a typo error, which implies to have been used an emdash as a sudden change of thought or what?

*I sit up in cold sweat on my bed and promise her questioning eyes that I will do my **bit-will** gather my faculties and stand up for you my baby. And her eyes invest a ‘childlike ‘trust in me. Yes, my child I owe it to you. Her eyes again throw a painful query at me- how can perpetuators of sin who violated my fragile body be given refugee - I fail to understand after withstanding pain beyond belief how can I be at fault?*

Comment: There is a typo: I will do my bit well - gather etc. There is an idiomatic expression: to do one's bit well. The dash comes after that. bit-will is gibberish.

Comment: I really do not understand  how you can choose an answer that doesn't even catch the typo.

Comment: @Lambie I don't believe there is a typo. There are two clauses, "I will do my bit" and "[I] will gather...". "Will" here is an auxiliary verb with "gather".

Comment: @Tashus I would have to see the original.

Comment: Where is this text?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, that should be an em dash**. The other two hyphens appearing later in the paragraph should also be dashes.

Many people rely on word processor programs or other types of automatically formatting text to convert hyphens to em dashes as appropriate. For example, Microsoft Word would probably have replaced that hyphen with an em dash once the spacebar was pressed after "will". Sometimes these systems fail, and sometimes people simply don't realize that their current text input system (e.g. Notepad) will not make this formatting change automatically. As a third option, plenty of native speakers may not really know the difference between hyphens, en dashes, and em dashes. Many people (wrongly) use the words "dash" and "hyphen" interchangeably in conversation, and they may use the different symbols interchangeably as well (again, incorrectly).

Comment: So, why did the author use emdash here. For what?

Comment: If emdash was written there- does it mean a sudden change of thought there. And, without space is it correct to put there between bit and will?

Comment: @Faizan The em dash is used to specify what "will do my bit" refers to. I'm not sure what you are asking in that second sentence, but it might be appropriate for a new question. I see you are a new contributor. Welcome to ell! We avoid using comments for back and forth discussion, so if you have more questions, consider making new posts.

Comment: Regardless of all this, there is a major typo.

Comment: @Lambie I don't see any typo. There is no reason to assume that "will" is a typo for "well".